# Solr - Seeing far less results than expected

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

I have uploaded 80000 lines with random text to Solr using requestHandler from DB.

Looking in the core overview I see that the lines were updated 
[image]

In the schema I defined all the string columns as in the following example

```
...
<field name="packageName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
...
```

I query using

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/vault/select/?q=everyone&fl=*
```

and I get no result though I know captain exists (cause I query

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Fact] where packageNAme like '%everyone%'
```

)
infact, only the following query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/vault/select/?q=*&fl=id
```

returns rows

Why dont I get rows using the first query?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Following this [tutorial](http://danpincas.com/2013/03/28/searching-with-solr-part-2.html) I was using this queries

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/products/select?q=aluminum  
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=video&fl=name,id
```

And it returned all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `everyone` is no keyword in `Solr`. According to your query `everyone` looks like a `keyword`.

Secondly - When you query the database you have `%` in front and behind for the matching. You have to do the same in case of the Solr query.

Try this - `http://localhost:8983/solr/vault/select?q=packageName:*everyone*`. This will get you the result same as the DB.

**Explanation** - In the query i sent you, you would be trying to match the field `packageName` with `everyone` having 0 or more characters before and/or after it.

For more information have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)

**Added information after edit in the question** -
The default `schema.xml` that comes with Solr has a field called `name` which is marked as the `default` search field, which means a `q=<search phrase>` will be matched against the `name` field. The tutorial that you are looking at is using the `name` field and hence they get the output.

Comment: Thanks. Working. Please see my edit. My type of query is from a tutorial.

Comment: Can you refer me to where in the tutorial was the name marked as default? Cant seem to see it

Comment: Saw it later. Answered it on the new question you posted.